# If people can see through my clothes, will I be Color Coordinated?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

One of the Diablo 3 "exploration" achievements is Color Coordinated:

> Equip your head, shoulders, torso, legs, feet, and hands slots with items dyed the same color.

I don't particularly care for any of the dyes available, so I'm considering using Vanishing Dye to get this achievement:

> Renders a single piece of armor invisible.

"Invisible" really isn't a color, though, even though it is technically a "dye."  I don't particularly want to invest a couple of grand in dye if I won't get the achievement for using it.  Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though it's not a part of the Rainbow Connection dye list, I've confirmed that Vanishing Dye **does** work for Made It Work, and thus should work for Color Coordinated as well.

Comment: And if it doesn't, I'll pay the cost of your dyes, because I'm curious now too..

Comment: Vanishing Dye appears to work for this, in addition to the Born to Dye achievement - so apparently "invisible" is a color after all :P